# How to make a picture in GUI form always in the center with any screen resolution?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I want to make those 2 of my picture always in the center, no matter resolution size is. 
I tried this code, These pictures just in the center in my work screen (1936,
1056) . When I tried in other screen with different resolution, the picture is not in the center.
Anyone can help me please.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.BackColor                  = "#fcfcfc"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'


$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile(".\AT3.png")
$pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox

$img2 = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile(".\AT2.png")
$pictureBox2 = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox

$Panel1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Panel


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Panel1))
$Panel1.controls.AddRange(@($pictureBox2,$pictureBox))


[void]$Form.Show()


$Panel1.height                   = $Form.Height / 2
$Panel1.width                    = $Form.Width
$Panel1.Anchor                   = "None"
$Panel1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(1,($Panel1.height/2))
$Panel1.BackColor                  = "#fcfcfc"

$pictureBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Panel1.width/2.5),($Panel1.height/2.5))
$pictureBox2.Width = $Form.Size.Width / 2
$pictureBox2.Height = $Form.Size.Height / 2
$pictureBox2.Image = $img2

$pictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Panel1.width/2.8),($Panel1.height/9))
$pictureBox.Width = $Form.Size.Width / 0.5
$pictureBox.Height = $Form.Size.Height / 0.5
$pictureBox.Image = $img

Write-Host $Form.Width
Write-Host $Form.Height

$Form.Visible = $false
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with the use of **anchors**. Or more precisely the **non use of them**.

Controls are anchored by default to the top left of the form which means when the form size will be changed, their distance from the top left side of the form will remain constant. If you change the control anchor to bottom left, then the control will keep the same distance from the bottom and left sides of the form when the form if resized.

Turning off the anchor in a direction will keep the control centered in that direction when resizing.

**NOTE**: Turning off anchoring via the properties window in VS2015 may require entering None, None (instead of default Top,Left)